# How to import project files without Gradle files into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to import a project into my Android Studio. It works well in Eclipse when my friend gave it to me.

But I couldn't import it into my Android Studio. And all the tutorial told me that I should add/edit the Gradle files when there is no Gradle files in this project. So what am I going to do without having to download the Eclipse IDE? Many thanks.

Comment: File->New-> Import Project.

Answer (score 3):

You can export the project from eclipse to a gradle project.

1. Right clicks your project.
2. Clicks the 'export' in the popup menu.
3. Choose Android > Generate gradle build files. (If there is not 'Generate gradle build files', maybe you need to install gradle plugin for eclipse: [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44))
   And then you can import this project on android studio.

Comment: Can this be done in android studio? I have no eclipse installed. The project is cloned from Internet.

Comment: @adamhj If you have android studios installed it can create a gradle build for an eclipse project by just importing the project ``File > New > Import Project...``

Answer (score 2):

Other people have said it here in the comments, the answer is inside Android Studio: File -> new -> import project